# Restricting allowable values of float argument

Tags: java, types, arguments

I'm a newbie in Java and I am working on program to manage Schedules.

Is it possible to restrict the value of a `float`, that is an argument for a function?

Since this is a schedule, the value of the hours have to be between `0` and `24`.

Comment: Define restrict. It's quite easy to do but what do you want to happen? Exception thrown or something else?

Comment: I know how to do it inside the function, that is, check with an if statement if it's comprehended between those values, and if it's not return an error and end the function. That is how I've been handling it so far. I would like to know if I can restrict in the function prototype @DominikAngerer

Comment: You cannot restrict a parameter further than specifying its type. You may want to create/use a `Time` class and pass an instance of this class as an argument to prevent "illegal" arguments from being passed as parameter.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a `Time` class or maybe `Date` to handle dates / times .

Comment: Are the valid hour values just the whole numbered values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple exception handling example would be:

```
     class ValidateDouble {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Your initial value
        double value = 0;
        System.out.println("Your initial value is: " + value);

        // Not valid argument, should print 0 as returned from method
        value = inputDouble(-1);
        System.out.println("After entering -1, your value is: " + value);

        // Not valid argument, should print 0 as returned from method
        value = inputDouble(-1.5);
        System.out.println("After entering -1.5, your value is: " + value);

        // Not valid argument, should print 0 as returned from method
        value = inputDouble(25);
        System.out.println("After entering 25, your value is: " + value);

        // Valid argument, should print the returned argument value
        value = inputDouble(2);
        System.out.println("\nAfter entering 2, your value is: " + value);

        // Valid argument, should print the returned argument value 
        value = inputDouble(2.54);
        System.out.println("\nAfter entering 2.54, your value is: " + value);

    }

    private static double inputDouble (double number) {

        // Program will try to execute this
        try {

            // If number is out of range, throw exception if not, return the argument.
            if (number < 0 || number > 24) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("\nNot a valid argument...");
            } else {
                return number;
            }

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {

            // Print message thrown in the exception and return 0.
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            return 0;
        }

    }

}
```

I know this is probably not what you are looking for, I have posted as an example based on your question, how to validate method arguments. There are a great deal of ways to validate your user inputs, but as long as you asked about validating a method argument, I think this can help you getting there. Cheers.

You will not be able to do that in the method prototype.

Comment: Thank you. I guess if it's not possible it just isn't. Sorry about such a late reply. :)